# Is it possible to compress Parquet file which contain Json data in hive external table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hiveql, parquet

I want to know how to compress Parquet file which contain Json data in hive external table. How can it be done?

I have created external table like this:

```
create table parquet_table_name3(id BIGINT,created_at STRING,source STRING,favorited BOOLEAN) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'parquet.hive.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' LOCATION '/user/cloudera/parquet2';
```

and I had set the compression properties

```
set parquet.compression=GZIP;
```

and compressed my input Parquet file  by executing

```
GZIP <file name> ( i.e 000000_0.Parquet)
```

after that i have load compresed GZIP file into hdfs location `/user/cloudera/parquet2`

next i have try to run the run the below query

```
select * from parquet_table_name3;
```

i am getting bellow result

```
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Can you please let me know why i am getting null value instead of result,  how to do parquet file compression(if it contain json data) in hive external table ? Can someone help me to compress in hive external table?

Answer (score 3):

Duh! You can't compress an existing Parquet file "from outside". It's a columnar format with a hellishly complicated internal structure, just like ORC; the file "skeleton" requires fast random access (i.e. no compression), and each data chunk has to be compressed separately because they are accessed separately.

It's when you **create** a new Parquet file that you request the SerDe library to compress data *inside* the file, based on the `parquet.compression` Hive property.
At read time, the SerDe then checks the compression codec of each data file and decompresses accordingly.

A quick Google search returns a couple of **must-reads** such as [this](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cdh_ig_parquet.html) and [that](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/28856/hive-table-format-and-compression.html).

Comment: This is also applicable to Apache Arrow - your language's library (Ruby, for example) may offer a compression option, but if it's compressing the .parquet file instead of telling Parquet to compress internally, it's not doing it correctly. Parquet GZip compression is NOT the same as gzip foo.parquet! This is not well documented and took me a while to understand.

Comment: You can deliver the same information without being condescending to OP.